# Why can't select my Ionic app on Play Console to make an AdWords Campaign?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, google-ads-api

I have upload an app to Google Play and I want to make an AdWords campaign. The problem is that I can't select the app to promote it. I don't know if the problem is related whith the code (maybe I need to include code for Google detect my app) or if I have to make something on AdWords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link your AdWords account to your developer account [as described here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6068602).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally I had to create an AdWords campaign for another app and then create the campaign for the app I wanted.